# Making iterative subplots in one subplot2grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I would like to have a window that is divided in 4 sectors: in the (0,0) a imshow image (ax1); (1,0) a subplot image that uses twinx() image that divides the window(ax2 & ax3); (1,1) a regular plot image (ax4); and an iterative section (0,1) of plots that should give "number_of_subplots" plots one above the other (ax5). Hopefully with no xticklabels but the last one.

[This is how the frame should look like before the iterative subplot creation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHhT9.png)

**My problem:** when iterating to create the subplots on the top right space of the window, the subplots span away from that space and eliminate the ax4

[This is how the window looks after the "for" cyle for the subplot creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ofs0.png)

Below you'll find a simplification of the code I am using, just so you can see it better. I have replaced my experimental data with random numbers so you can replicate this easily.

Could you give me a hint on what am I doing wrong? I still do not dominate all the handlers in python. I used to do similar things in matlab a few years ago.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
    import numpy as np
    import pdb

    pos = [1,2,3,4,5]
    N = 50
    x = np.random.rand(N)
    y = np.random.rand(N)

    xx = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)

    fig1 = plt.figure()
    number_of_subplots = len(pos) #number between 1-7
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((number_of_subplots+1,2),(0,0),rowspan = number_of_subplots-1) # Here the idea is to "dinamically" create the division of the grid, making space at the bottom of it for the image in the bottom left.
    ax1.scatter(x,y)

    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((number_of_subplots+1,2),(number_of_subplots-1,0), rowspan = 2)
    ax2.plot(xx,np.sin(xx),label = 'sin(x)',color = 'b')
    ax3 = ax2.twinx()
    ax3.plot(xx,np.cos(xx), label = 'cos(x)', color = 'r')

    ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((number_of_subplots+1,2),(number_of_subplots-1,1), rowspan = 2)
    ax4.plot(xx,np.tan(xx), label = 'tan(x)', color = 'g')

    for i,v in enumerate(xrange(number_of_subplots)):
            v = v+1
            ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((number_of_subplots+1,2),(v-1,1))
            ax5.plot(np.sin(xx+3.1416*v/2)) # Grafica los perfiles, asociandoles el mismo color que para los cortes en la imagen 2D
            if (i % 2 == 0): #Even
                    ax5.yaxis.tick_left()
            else:
                    ax5.yaxis.tick_right()
    plt.draw()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by using GridSpec as it is supposed to be used. Below is the implementation of the code that gives the following solution.

[This is the correct way the image should look like and the implementation is below on the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfpRZ.png)

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
    import numpy as np
    import pdb

    pos = [1,2,3,4,5]

    N = 50
    x = np.random.rand(N)
    y = np.random.rand(N)

    xx = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)

    number_of_subplots = len(pos) #number between 1-7

    fig1 = plt.figure()

    gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2,height_ratios=[3,1],hspace=0.1)
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs0[0,0])
    ax2 = plt.subplot(gs0[-1,0])
    ax4 = plt.subplot(gs0[-1,-1])

    gs2 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(number_of_subplots, 1, subplot_spec=gs0[1],wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

    ax1.scatter(x,y)

    ax2.plot(xx,np.sin(xx),label = 'sin(x)',color = 'b')
    ax3 = ax2.twinx()
    ax3.plot(xx,np.cos(xx), label = 'cos(x)', color = 'r')

    ax4.plot(xx,np.tan(xx), label = 'tan(x)', color = 'g')

    for i in enumerate(xrange(number_of_subplots)):
            ax5 = plt.subplot(gs2[i,:])
            ax5.plot(np.sin(xx+3.1416*i/2)) 
            if (i % 2 == 0): #Even
                    ax5.yaxis.tick_left()
            else:
                    ax5.yaxis.tick_right()
    plt.draw()
    plt.show()
```